# Scala Either with List

Tags: scala, types, either, higher-kinded-types

I wanted to implement a similar type called `Result` to the `Either` type. The main difference is, that the Left side of the `Result` type should always be a List of something. What would be the right type definition for this? I tried having something like that:

```
sealed trait Result[List, +A] {
    def map[B](f: A => B): Result[List, B] = this match {
        case Failure(err) => Failure(err)
        case Success(value) => Success(f(value))
    }
    def apply[B](f: Result[List, A => B]): Result[List, B] = (f, this) match {
        case (Failure(fE), Failure(aE)) => Failure(fE ::: aE)
        case ...
    }
}

final case class Failure[+E](errors: List[E]) extends Result[List[E], Nothing]
final case class Success[+A](value: A) extends Result[Nothing, A]
```

But this runs in an error in the map function saying `Failure[Any] does not equal Result[List, B]` and `Success[B] does not equal Result[List, B]`. Is the type definition `Result[List, +A]` already wrong, should I use a higher-kinded type like `List[_]` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that the left side is *always* `List` of something, then there is no need to abstract over the `List`. Abstract over `E`:

```
sealed trait Result[+E, +A] {
    def map[B](f: A => B): Result[E, B] = this match {
        case Failure(err) => Failure(err)
        case Success(value) => Success(f(value))
    }
    def apply[B, F >: E](f: Result[F, A => B]): Result[F, B] = (f, this) match {
        case (Failure(fE), Failure(aE)) => Failure(fE ::: aE)
        case (Failure(fE), _) => Failure(fE)
        case (_, Failure(aE)) => Failure(aE)
        case (Success(fS), Success(tS)) => Success(fS(tS))
    }
}

case class Failure[+E](errors: List[E]) extends Result[E, Nothing]
case class Success[+A](value: A) extends Result[Nothing, A]
```

Note that it looks as if you are reinventing some standard `Applicative`s from Scalaz/Cats.

Comment: I still get the same error Saying Failure[Any] doesn't equal Railway[E,B], and I need the List properties if I want to implement some kind of apply function. I'll update my question to explain that

Comment: @Lando-L the above code definitely compiles. I've updated the `apply` part. My guess is that you've done something wrong with the variance annotations.

Comment: I don't know what I have done wrong, I thought I had the exact same code. Thank you!

Comment: @Lando-L I assume it was a missing `+` before `List` somewhere. Does it work now?